# Rails 3.1 and CKEditor w Carrierwave, cannot upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, carrierwave

Uploading files won't work for me. The file does get saved but looking at the parameters there is no authenticity token sent by CKeditor. So I get a "Can't verify CSRF authenticity" warning, which resets the session, then I can't update the post.

The token is set in the form but CKEditor doesn't seem to send it for picture or file uploads. I think this may have been OK when I used CKE with Paperclip, but not certain of that. All other CKE operations work.

Comment: I think the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398707/ruby-on-rails-problem-getting-ckeditor-to-upload-images may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Answered at [Ruby on Rails: problem getting CKeditor to upload images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398707/ruby-on-rails-problem-getting-ckeditor-to-upload-images)

You need to skip verification

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:new_from_disk]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see the ckeditor code:

```
class Ckeditor::ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
```

Please add some alike:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```