# Ajax Uploading via CKeditor gem to Rails kiling session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, file-upload, ckeditor, csrf

I am using the CKeditor Gem in my Rails 3.2.13/Backbone App

Backbone lets the users update their information via the API perfectly fine. But as soon as I try to upload a picture via CKeditor, it kills my session and says I am not authorized to make that change. So the API rejects the save and spits out a 401 Unauthorized, as it should.

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  render :json => Scientist.includes(:profile, :titles, :websites)
  .find(params[:id]), :status => :unauthorized
end
```

Using CanCan w/rolify. And no, i didn't configure the the gem to use authorization. However, when I did configure it, to use CanCan, it still failed, so it is definitely a sessions problem.

I've checked the headers and the X-CSRF-Token is there and it is correct (at least it matches what is shown in the meta tag). I think I am missing something here... I've been going through the sessions rails guide to find out why it is being killed but no clue still.

I found this question [Rails 3.1 and CKEditor w Carrierwave, cannot upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580969/rails-3-1-and-ckeditor-w-carrierwave-cannot-upload)

the gist of that answer was use

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:new_from_disk]`

But I rather not leave myself open to CSRF if I can prevent it. I also am not sure where I would use this line when the gem is handling the controllers and models for me.

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The same error for me.
The ckeditor controller do not anything for this csrf protection.
So the best way is to skip it unless you want to change the ckeditor's default uploader html and js code.

Mycode:

```
class Ckeditor::ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
...
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
...
end
```